# Jython exception handling within loops

Tags: python, exception, jython, automated-tests

I am using Marathon 2.0b4 to automate tests for an application.

A shortcoming of `wait_p`, one of the script elements provided by Marathon, is that its default timeout is **hardcoded** to be 60 seconds. I needed a larger timeout due to the long loading times in my application.
[I considered patching Marathon, but didn't want to maintain parallel versions etc., so figured that a better solution would actually be a workaround at the test script level.]

```
def wait_p_long(times, compID_name, ppty_name, ppty_value, compID_cell=None):
    from marathon.playback import *
    """Wrapper around wait_p which takes exactly the same parameters as wait_p,
    except that an extra first parameter is used to specify the number of times
    wait_p is called"""
    for i in range(1, times):
        try:
            wait_p(compID_name, ppty_name, ppty_value, compID_cell)
        except:
            if (i < times):
                print "wait_p failed, trying again"
            else:
                raise
```

`wait_p` is short for "wait property", and it takes in 3 compulsory and one optional argument (the argument's names are rather self-explanatory), and what it does is wait for a speicifed property of the specified component to be equals to the specified value.

What the above method (Jython) intends to do is take one extra parameter, `times`, which specifies the number of times to attempt `wait_p`, suppressing the exceptions up until the last try.

However, this method isn't working for me, and I am afraid there might be some syntactical or logical error somewhere in there. Any comments from python / jython gurus out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

- `range(1, times)` should almost certainly be `range(times)`; what you wrote is equivalent to `for (int i=1; i < times; i++)`
- Because of what I just explained, `if (i < times)` will always be `True` in your `except` block

If this doesn't help with your problem, please describe how exactly your results are differing from what you expect.

The results would look something like:

```
def wait_p_long(times, compID_name, ppty_name, ppty_value, compID_cell=None):
    from marathon.playback import *
    """
    Wrapper around wait_p which takes exactly the same parameters as wait_p,
    except that an extra first parameter is used to specify the number of times
    wait_p is called.
    """
    for i in range(times):
        try:
            wait_p(compID_name, ppty_name, ppty_value, compID_cell)
        except:
            if i == times - 1:
                raise
            else:
                print "wait_p failed, trying again"
```

Comment: I feel like such a n00b now! Just to clarify your suggestions: 1) Change `range(1, times)` to `range(times)`  and 2) Change `if (i < times)` to `if (i < (times -1))`; in order to capture the last occurence of the for loop?

Answer (score 3):

@Hank's explanation is correct, but I would suggest a different approach:

```
def wait_p_long(times, compID_name, ppty_name, ppty_value, compID_cell=None):
    from marathon.playback import *
    for i in range(times-1):
        try:
                wait_p(compID_name, ppty_name, ppty_value, compID_cell)
                break
        except:
                pass
     else:  # try one last time...!
         wait_p(compID_name, ppty_name, ppty_value, compID_cell)
```

It feels conceptually simpler to me (though the textual repetition of the `wait_p` call is a minus, it avoids checks on `i` to do something different "the last time around").  The `else` clause on a loop executes if no `break` ever executed in the loop, btw.

Comment: Thank Alex, but I think I prefer Hank's solution. +1 for you still!

Comment: OK, but that solution as currently coded is buggy -- the test `if (i == times):`, besides the redundant parentheses, will never be satisfied, so the `raise` will never happen.  The point is not this specific bug, which can of course be fixed: it's that the kind of coding you and Hank are using is **bug-prone** -- it's just too easy to have an off-by-one bug.  Coding it the way I suggest (and thanks for the +1, btw) is just less bug-prone -- which is why you _should_ prefer it;-). Give it a few decades, and you'll learn which idioms and approaches are less bug-prone **and** will prefer them!-)

Comment: @Alex thanks for pointing out the bug; I'll fix that immediately. For the record, I like your approach more but was trying to get bguiz's example to work with minimal conceptual changes.